# Internet-explorer 8 trys to download pages in firewall pattern

Tags: html, internet-explorer, symfony, internet-explorer-8

in my app/security.yml  i have a secured pattern like

```
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/secured/
```

everything works fine and as expected

only IE < 9 prompts with a download dialogue instead of viewing the html file

everything super correct, headers are text/html and the downlaoded file ( without extension )  contains the html !?

i found only one link, of someone describing the problem

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/internet-explorer-downloading-htmhtml-instead-of/ea25e134-e476-4709-881c-fa6e85edefe2

but not in context with symfony, im sure its not a symfony problem at all-

**however** if i remove the route from the secured_area pattern, it works ! 
microsoft works!

Comment: which web server are you using?

Comment: using Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, seems like internet-explorer 8 doesnt send any accept-headers.
And in this case our fosRest bundle-configuration delivered as fallback-content type application/json, and because ie8 doesnt know die content-type it tryed to download

we finally found out with a telnet request without accept header that appliction/json was delivered.So we changed the fallback format  in config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        default_priorities: ['html', 'json', '*/*']
        fallback_format: html
```